# Developer mode not working correctly when set via cli

Tags: magento2, developer-mode

I decided to switch my testing area from production to development for a quick fiddle and barely any of the static files were generated once visiting site after setting mode with below command.

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

This has always worked in the past however today has been another story. After loads of files just not being generated and seeing lots of 404 for js / css files and require js errors now I just seem to get this:

```
Unable to retrieve deployment version of static files from the file system.
```

OR

```
Warning: include(/home/sites/magento/testing_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sites/magento/testing_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php on line 326
```

This may just be a permissions issue but have set various ways and nothing seems to work great.

After a couple hours of fiddling with permissions and flushing / disabling cache. Running setup:upgrade and anything else I could think if I discovered that developer mode now only seems to work if set with the **.htaccess**.

```
SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer
```

Not ideal so just wondering if anyone knows a solution or why this might be occurring like this?

Comment: make sure you have env.php updated and clean php cache

Comment: Yeah tried both above. Still that files not generated although a lot of others are.

Comment: maybe delete everything from 'rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/* pub/static/frontend/*' and run the 'php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy' command. atleast that always works for me

Comment: Yeah if i wack it into production and deploy static content everything works fine.